# In spring MVC How do I map same URL with different controller methods based on the payload?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have POST /users URL I want to pass array of users or single user depending on the payload. I would like to map it with different method in spring.

e.g.

POST /users

[
  {
    "firstname":"test1",
    "lastname":"test1"
  },
  { 
    "firstname":"test2",
    "lastname":"test2"
  }
]

should go to

controller's createBulk(Users[] users) method

and

POST /users

{
    "firstname":"test1",
    "lastname":"test1"
  },
  { 
    "firstname":"test2",
    "lastname":"test2"
  }

should go to

controller's createUser(Users users) method

Comment: why not check `users.size()` inside `createUser(Users users)` and if size is big enough call `createBulk`?

Comment: check the consumes attribute if you use the latest Spring MVC?

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to annotate same RequestMapping with the same RequestMethod on different java-class method, but you can judge to do what things(go which process) via your requirement, the following shows an example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser() {
     if (some condition) 
         // do sth. e.g:create bulk
     else
         // do oth. e.g:create user
}
```

Maybe help you:)

Comment: I am relying on spring binding to extract data from my request using @RequestBody, with this approach I need to manually extract the requestBody.